# Highlight a term inside another already highlighted term in mark.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) library in order to do text highlight. It works fine, but I wonder how can I highlight a term twice.

The library allows the user to specify the class name for the highlight, so to my understanding, if a long term is highlighted once, and later you want to highlight a substring of that term with a different class (to apply a different style with css), that's where I run into trouble.

I have tried this:

```
<div id="article">
  This is a dummy text including used in training systems
</div>
```

And then

```
longTerms = ["training systems"]
shortTerms = ["systems"]

longTerms.forEach(function(term) {

  $("#article").mark(term, {
    "className": "orange",
    "separateWordSearch": false,
    "accuracy": "exactly",
    "acrossElements": true
  });

});

shortTerms.forEach(function(term) {

  $("#article").mark(term, {
    "className": "underline",
    "separateWordSearch": false,
    "accuracy": "exactly",
    "acrossElements": true
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle with the CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/rubenwap/n3h1ca76/1/)

I am having success in getting "Training systems" highlighted using the `.orange` class, but I cannot get "systems" underlined, as it should according to the `.underline` class.

Why can't I apply an additional class to the one I already have?

Comment: Mark the words `Training` and `Systems` separately with `orange` class on `Training` and both `orange underline` on `Systems`

Comment: I cannot, as this system is meant to highlight full sentences. I cannot highlight the words one by one, I should catch the full sentence string.

Comment: Ok. how do you decide which one to highlight and which one to underline ?

Comment: There's already an existing [issue](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues/95) and it's currently not possible to mark matches within an already marked match. I'd recommend to participate yourself in the discussion to give this a higher priority.

Comment: Thanks @dude, I just commented in the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a proper way of doing, 
But as it is not possible to mark already marked item using `mark.js`, you can do something like below to get it working temporarily :

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/suzo/n3h1ca76/2/)

```
longTerms = ["training systems"]
shortTerms = ["systems"]


longTerms.forEach(function(term) {

  $("#article").mark(term, {
    "className": "orange",
    "separateWordSearch": false,
    "accuracy": "exactly",
    "acrossElements": true
  });
}); 


markSubString('#article', 1 , 'orange underline');

function markSubString (parent, subStringIndex, classes) {
    var subElement = ' <mark data-markjs="true" class="' + classes + '">';
    var markedElement = $(parent + ' mark');
    var textToMark = markedElement[0].textContent;
    var allSubStrings = textToMark.split(' ');
    var newText = '';
    markedElement.text('');

    for(var i = 0; i < allSubStrings.length; i++){

     if(i === subStringIndex){
        newText += subElement + allSubStrings[i] + ' </mark>';
     } else {
        newText += allSubStrings[i] + ' ';
     }
   }

    markedElement.append(newText);
}
```

pass the `parent` element like `#article` if it's an id, `index of the word that needs to be marked inside the actual string that has already been marked` and `class names that needs to be added` to `markSubString` method. I just wrote a basic generic method to do this,it can be improved.

Comment: Thanks, this actually accomplishes what I was looking for!

Comment: Cool. No problem, Glad I could help :)

Comment: Seems to be possible now with [v8.7.0](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/releases/tag/8.7.0)